# push button on the same composite of radio group is getting focus for arrow keys

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

Push button with a group of radio buttons on the same composite getting focus for arrow keys which is supposed to be used for selecting an option from radio group.

can we prevent this for PUSH button from getting focused to arrow keys. Is there any way ??

Here is the sample code .

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class SWTButtons {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);   

    //radio
    Button[] radioButtons = new Button[3];
    radioButtons[0] = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    radioButtons[0].setSelection(true);
    radioButtons[0].setText("Choice 1");
    radioButtons[0].setLocation(50,150);
    radioButtons[0].pack();

    radioButtons[1] = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    radioButtons[1].setText("Choice 2");
    radioButtons[1].setLocation(120,150);
    radioButtons[1].pack();

    radioButtons[2] = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    radioButtons[2].setText("Choice 3");
    radioButtons[2].setLocation(190,150);
    radioButtons[2].pack();
    //Text
    Text textBox =  new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    textBox.setText("Test");
    textBox.setLocation(260,  150);
    textBox.pack();

    //push button
    Button pushButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    pushButton.setLocation(100, 250);
    pushButton.setText("Get Value (push button)");
    pushButton.pack();


    shell.setSize(500,500);
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

Comment: Why not put the button in a different composite?

Comment: Yes, it will work. I am just curious , it this the expected behavior with PUSH button?   And moreover i have many combinations of radio groups with buttons so i am afraid i cant use compositions for every such scenario

Comment: The thing is that they are all `Button`s. If you would use tab to navigate, you could use `setTabList()` of the `Shell` to specify which you want to gain focus.